# How to match and replace value from one dataframe to another?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, match

I have a dataframe `df`

```
df = data.frame("A" = c("car",NA,"cat","cut"),
                "B" = c(NA,"car",NA,"cat"),
                "C" = c("cut","cat",NA,NA))
```

and another one `df2`

```
df2 = data.frame("Group" = c("car", "cat","cut"),
                 "Value" = c(1,2,3))
```

I would like to have the output like this

```
     A    B    C
1    1   NA    3
2   NA    1    2
3    2   NA   NA
4    3    2   NA
```

I am relative new to R so I need some help in solving this. Thanks!

Comment: In case you're interested in the performance of some of the different approaches to this, see [these tests and benchmarks](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/0e50d7601e99027d94451572bbaf7db4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `unlist` the dataframe and use `match` :

```
df[] <- df2$Value[match(unlist(df), df2$Group)]
df

#   A  B  C
#1  1 NA  3
#2 NA  1  2
#3  2 NA NA
#4  3  2 NA
```

---

To solve this using `dplyr` you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(.fns = ~df2$Value[match(., df2$Group)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `factor`:

```
df_new <- df # just in case you want to retain your original df
df_new[] <- lapply(df, factor, levels = df2$Group, labels = df2$Value)
df_new 
#      A    B    C
# 1    1 <NA>    3
# 2 <NA>    1    2
# 3    2 <NA> <NA>
# 4    3    2 <NA>
```

Note that the values are characters, though. To get numeric values, you can do `lapply(df, function(x) as.integer(as.character(factor(x, levels = df2$Group, labels = df2$Value))))`.

Alternatively, you can do:

```
df_new[] <- factor(as.matrix(df), levels = df2$Group, labels = df2$Value)
```

This will again return a `data.frame` with character columns. Get numeric values by using `as.integer(as.character(factor(as.matrix(df), levels = df2$Group, labels = df2$Value)))`.

---

If your value column is always just a sequential integer, you can skip the "labels" argument and the `as.character` before using `as.integer`. Furthermore, you can simplify the extraction of numeric values by using `data.matrix`.

---

These have been benchmarked [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/0e50d7601e99027d94451572bbaf7db4).